# How to use Domain Codes set in a Feature Class when opening the Feature Class in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, domains

If I set domain codes on a feature class, does this translate into MS Access as well?

For example, I set a domain code and use it on a field in the feature class, I can then go into ArcMap, start an edit session and click on cells in the field and I get the drop down set by the domains. What I want to know is, can you open the feature class in MS access and use that domain drop down? I tried this and the drop down doesn't populate. I'm wondering if there's something I need to enable to get this?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb and say no. Coded value domains are an ArcGIS feature, not an Access one. Maybe there is some unsupported backdoor way of doing what you want but I doubt its going to be clean or easy. As a general rule you should avoid editing personal geodatabases in Access anyways.